# Implement Consume Type with generic in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

I hope to implement string consumer with generic in typescript for excluding duplication in array and prevent misused.

For example let's here is a date format order

`["year", "month", "day"]`

We can present type of this array: `Array<"year" | "month" | "day">

but there is a problem user can write duplicated value like this.

```js
type DateOrder = ["year" | "month" | "day"]

// work
const dateFormatOrder: DateOrder = ["year", "month", "day"]

// it is work too but should be error.
const dateFormatOrder: DateOrder = ["year", "year", "year"]


// also should be worked, all values are should be used.
const dateFormatOrder = [“month”, “day”,”year”]
```

So, is there something way for restrict already used value with generic in typescript ?

Comment: `DateOrder` is an array of a single element that is "year" or "month" or "day", so I'm seeing errors on both of those as you assign arrays with three elements.

Comment: `type DateOrder = ("year" | "month" | "day")[];` *will* exhibit the "problem" you indicate.

Comment: You could generate all possible permutations: https://tsplay.dev/WKPbpw but this will be really slow for larger unions.

Comment: ① Do you need to use all the values? Right now you're just saying there should be no duplicates, but it's not 100% clear whether you are allowed to leave some out.  That is: `["year", "year", "year"]` is bad, but is `["year", "month"]` okay? ② There is no scalable specific type that works this way (unless you only have a handful of types).  Would you accept something of the form `const dateFormatOrder = asDateOrder("year", "month", "day")` than enforces your constraint (once you tell us what the constraint is)?

Comment: I am also talking about TypeScript and not JavaScript, so I'm not sure why you're bringing that up.

Comment: 1. I don’t need to implement in javascript. I wish resolving as typescript. You should know about why we must seperate type system and running system. 2. All value should be used. 3. I think it seems no way to except using generic. So answer has been expected with generics @jcalz

Comment: "All value should be used" Okay, please [edit] the question to say that

Comment: Oh, your link seems like to resolve my question plz write as answer. @jcalz

Comment: Are you talking about what @pink wrote? I didn't provide a link

Comment: oh I have misunderstand, sorry. typescriptlang website is not support mobile well. anyways, @pink ‘s link would resolve my question. can you write answer ?

Comment:  Okay I will disengage now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253142/discussion-between-cyan-kinesin-and-jcalz).

Comment: it is not entire completed answer, but looks like to resolve myself using typescript indexed access. Thx ! @jcalz